# Center div with jquery with unknown width

Tags: jquery, css, html, center

I have a div in fixed position that i like to make it center of my browser..

Of course it can be done with css, but the thing is i`m changing element's width in several times (loading something by ajax, so the width will change!) ...

So i want centering the div after changing its width by jquery.

For centering i use this code:
http://manos.malihu.gr/center-div-with-jquery

But when i changing div's width, it doesn't become in center even after calling CenterItem again!

Bottom line, i want something like this: 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/lightbox2/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the script in your link, call the Centeritem function on the resize event on the element as well as on the window.

```
$('#ElementsID').resize(function() {
    CenterItem('.centered');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use JQuery at all? CSS can easily center items, even with variable (and changing) widths.

[Example here.](http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm)